# TypeError: Error #1009 - (Null reference error) With Flash

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am not an expert in flash, but I do work with AS and tweak Flash projects, though not having deep expertise in it. Currently I need to revamp a flash website done by one another guy, and the code base given to me, upon execution is throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at NewSite_fla::MainTimeline/__setProp_ContactOutP1_ContactOut_Contents_0()
at NewSite_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

The structure of the project is like, it has the different sections split into different movie clips. There is no single main timeline, but click actions on different areas of seperate movie clips will take them between one another. All the AS logic of event handling are written inline in FLA , no seperate Document class exists.

Preloader Movie clip is the first one getting loaded. As i understood the error is getting thrown initially itself, and it is not happening due to any Action script logic written inline, because it is throwing error even before hitting the first inline AS code.

I am not able to figure out what exactly is causing the problem, or where to resolve it. [I setup the stuff online, for reference if anybody want to take a look at it, and here is the link](http://arun.manusis.com/ap/NewSite.html). You need to have flash debugger turned ON in your browser, if need to see the exception getting triggered.

I really got stuck at this point. Any help will be great. I had not seen the particular solution I am looking for anywhere yet, though Error #1009 is common.

Comment: in frame 1 of your main timeline in NewSite.fla look through the actions and find anything that might look similar to ContactOutP1, or something familiar. Error #1009 basically means, you are using a variable(a reference) thas has not been initialized with a value yet(is null or undefined). The slow but sure method is go to the part of the code that starts up everything and comment out the rest of the calls aside from the 1st. Check if everything is properly initialized, if so move on...line by line debugging kinda'.

Comment: Also look out for common problems with scattered timeline code: instances being renamed, but code not being updated / paths to movie clips no longer point correctly / movie being initialized, although it isn't fully loaded / etc.

Comment: But in this particular project, there is no main timeline( infact i know there shoudl be a maintimeline), or i had not seen one. I only saw individual movieclips. 

Also remember, it is not going even up to the first action script code which is written. i removed the reference for contact out from all places, which is in the code and still no luck.

For these sort of a project if a maintimeline exist, can you tell me where can i look for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the option "Export at frame 1" for the classes in your library?

I get this error for instance:

I have a circle which is a Circle class and put it on Frame 10.
If I try to attach a eventHandler to it from frame 1, I get this error.
Set the option "Export at frame 1" for my Circle class will solve this issue for me.

Comment: I was not aware of it till now. Well i will try that and let you know here the result.Not sure wethere it will solve our problem or not.

Comment: Well,
 The option of Export at frame is set at 1, but no luck. Is there  anything else i can try out ?

Comment: Hey Guys, I got the solution, and it is really wiered.I initially was trying with FlashCS4 in mac. Now i tried it in windows with Flash CS3 and the damn file just got compiled and is working fine. I am not sure what is the problem with mac, but as long as i m able to proceed its fine. Anyways, Thanks for your help.